# Open Fusion Table Layer info window onchange

Tags: google-fusion-tables

Using generated code from FusionTablesLayer Wizard, I am trying to determine how to open the info window onchange. The code below displays the marker perfectly, but I would like the info window to open when a different selection (state) is selected, rather than clicking on the marker to trigger info window. Thanks.

Followup:

Following geocodezip's remarks below, the following code works well and has given me a great start! Now to use drop down selector rather than sidebar links...

New working code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <title>Fusion Table Markers and Sidebar</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['table']});
  var map;
  var markers = [];
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  function initialize() {
    var us = new google.maps.LatLng(38.24676420846342, -94.82073772499997);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
     center: us,
     zoom: 4,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   });


//sidebar to contain link to map marker - Sales Region - and Rep name  
    var sql = encodeURIComponent("SELECT 'State - Sales Region', 'Representative Contact', Lat, Lon FROM 5555555555 ORDER BY 'State - Sales Region'");
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=' + sql);

    query.send(getData);
  }

//simple sidebar and info window style 
  function getData(response) {
    var dt = response.getDataTable();  

    var side_html = '<table style="border-collapse: collapse" border="1" \
                       cellpadding="5"> \
                       <thead> \
                         <tr style="background-color:#e0e0e0"> \
                           <th>Area</th> \
                           <th>Name</th> \
                         </tr> \
                       </thead> \
                       <tbody>';

    for (var i = 0; i < dt.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
      var lat = dt.getValue(i,2);
      var lng = dt.getValue(i,3);
      var area = dt.getValue(i,0);
      var pop = dt.getValue(i,1);

      var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
      var html = "<strong>" + area + "</strong><br />" + pop;

      side_html += '<tr> \
                      <td><a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')">' + area + '</a></td> \
                      <td>' + pop + '</td> \
                    </tr>';

      createMarker(pt, html);

    }

    side_html += '</tbody> \
                </table>';
    document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_html;
  }

//use simple default marker
  function createMarker(point,info) { 
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: point,
      map: map
  });

    markers.push(marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infoWindow.close();
      infoWindow.setContent(info);
      infoWindow.open(map,marker); 
    });
  }

  function myclick(num) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[num], "click");
    map.setCenter(markers[num].getPosition());
//    map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+2);
  }


  </script>

</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 900px; height: 600px; position: absolute; left: 10px"></div>
  <div id="side_bar" style="width: 200px; height: 600px; position: absolute; left: 920px; overflow: auto;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to open an InfoWindow on a FusionTablesLayer by default is to click on it.  To open it from an external event, one option is to create your own InfoWindow. retrieving the content by querying the FusionTable and opening on whatever external stimulus you want.

[Example/proof of concept with a sidebar](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_Watershed_Stewards_Map_sidebar2.html)

[Example from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/open_infowindow)

Comment: Thanks. Being new to this, I was hoping to draw off of: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/open_infowindow